# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Recursive SQL - Is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursive-query

I have the following table:

```
| Article-Material1 | Article-Material2 |
|-------------------|-------------------|
| article001        | article002        |
| article001        | article003        |
| article001        | material001       |
| material001       |                   |
| article002        | article004        |
| article002        | material002       |
| material002       |                   |
| article003        | material003       |
| material003       |                   |
| article004        | material004       |
| material004       |                   |
| article005        | article010        |
| article005        | article011        |
| article005        | material001       |
| article010        | material005       |
| material005       |                   |
| article011        | article012        |
| article011        | material004       |
| article011        | material006       |
| material006       |                   |
| article012        | material002       |
| article012        | material007       |
| material007       |                   |
```

And i want to achieve an ouput like this:

```
article001
    |- article002
        |- article004
            |- material004
        |- material002
    |- article003
        |- material003
    |- material001
article005
    |- article010
        |- material005
    |- article011
        |- article012
            |- material002
            |- material007
        |- material004
        |- material006
    |- material001
```

I have no idea if this is possible with SQL. If it is not possible, what else could I try to get in the right direction?

Comment: how would that output look in a table form? or is it one string formatted in that manner?

Comment: It's possible, but your output isn't a table. Are you intending for the SQL to print something? Return XML? Include empty columns? Repeat column values? SQL Server has no concept of nested tables (most database systems don't, there are rare exceptions).

Comment: @Stephen That's one of my many problems with this. I don't know how to put this in an table. I need one row with all the sub elements for every main article (articles that only live on the first hierachy). And i need to know on wich hierachy level the sub elements live. The final goal is to export the data to an Excel file. In the excel file i need the ouput like above.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I hoped that there is something like nested data. This would certainly have made the task easier.

Comment: in other words, some thing like `Parent, child1, .... child(n)`?

Comment: Again, do you want print something or return the data is a table structure? those are very different task. Recursive query are very possible in SQL SERVER, just google `Recursive Query`

Comment: Excel doesn't nest cells either. It can present grouped items (rather clumsily) through outlines, but that requires a lot of manual fiddling. In its treatment of cells, Excel is much more like SQL Server than your desired tree of materials. So that just shifts the question to -- what should your Excel cells contain? Is it even useful for the end user to have it in that format? Is this just for a visual overview or are the cell contents going to be used for further calculations?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve a table structure. Something like Stephen mentioned: `Parent, child1, .... child(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Article-Material1] varchar(25),[Article-Material2] varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('article001','article002'),
('article001','article003'),
('article001','material001'),
('material001',null),
('article002','article004'),
('article002','material002'),
('material002',null),
('article003','material003'),
('material003',null),
('article004','material004'),
('material004',null),
('article005','article010'),
('article005','article011'),
('article005','material001'),
('article010','material005'),
('material005',null),
('article011','article012'),
('article011','material004'),
('article011','material006'),
('material006',null),
('article012','material002'),
('article012','material007'),
('material007',null)


Declare @Top    varchar(25) = null       --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 'article002' 
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with  cte0 as (
       Select ID=[Article-Material2]
             ,Pt=[Article-Material1]
       From   @YourTable
       Where  [Article-Material2] is not null
       Union All
       Select ID=[Article-Material1]
             ,Pt=null
       From   @YourTable
       Where  [Article-Material1] not in (Select [Article-Material2] from @YourTable where [Article-Material2] is not null) )               
,     cteP as (
      Select Distinct
             Seq  = cast(ID as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,Pt
            ,Lvl=1
      From   cte0 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,'X') = case when @Top is null then isnull(Pt,'X') else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(p.Seq+'.'+r.ID+r.Pt as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.Pt
            ,p.Lvl+1
      From   cte0 r
      Join   cteP p on r.Pt = p.ID and r.Pt=p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP )
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select Distinct
       A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.ID
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.Seq=B.Seq where R2>=R1
 Order By A.R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Now, just for fun, set **@Top** to **'article002'**  and you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

For presentation purpose you can use the following code, based on a previous post of mine.
[SQL Challenge/Puzzle: How to create an ASCII art hierarchy tree with an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925938/sql-challenge-puzzle-how-to-create-an-ascii-art-hierarchy-tree-with-an-sql-quer)

```
with        h (id,pid)
            as
            (
                select      [Article-Material2] as id
                           ,[Article-Material1] as pid

                from        mytable

                where       [Article-Material2] is not null

                union all

                select      distinct
                            [Article-Material1]     as id
                           ,null                    as pid

                from        mytable

                where       [Article-Material1] not in (select [Article-Material2] from mytable where [Article-Material2] is not null)
            )       

           ,last_sibling (id)
            as
            (
                select      max (id)
                from        h
                group by    pid
            )

           ,tree (id,branch,path)
            as
            (
                select      h.id
                           ,cast ('' as varchar(max))
                           ,cast (h.id as varchar(max))

                from        h

                where       h.pid is null

                union all

                select      h.id
                           ,t.branch + case when (select 1 from last_sibling ls where ls.id = t.id) = 1 then ' ' else '|' end + '    '
                           ,t.path + '_' + h.id

                from                    tree            t

                            join        h

                            on          h.pid =
                                        t.id
            )

           ,vertical_space (n)
            as
            (
                select      1

                union all

                select      vs.n + 1
                from        vertical_space  vs
                where       vs.n < 2
            )

select      t.branch + case vs.n when 1 then '|____' + ' ' + t.id else '|' end

from                    tree            t

            cross join  vertical_space  vs

order by    t.path
           ,vs.n desc

option      (maxrecursion 0)
;
```

---

```
|
|____ article001
|    |
|    |____ article002
|    |    |
|    |    |____ article004
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |____ material004
|    |    |
|    |    |____ material002
|    |
|    |____ article003
|    |    |
|    |    |____ material003
|    |
|    |____ material001
|
|____ article005
     |
     |____ article010
     |    |
     |    |____ material005
     |
     |____ article011
     |    |
     |    |____ article012
     |    |    |
     |    |    |____ material002
     |    |    |
     |    |    |____ material007
     |    |
     |    |____ material004
     |    |
     |    |____ material006
     |
     |____ material001
```